# Match string in python regardless of upper and lower case differences

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a match value from a keyword using python. My values are stored in a list (`my_list`) and in the below example I'm trying to find the word 'Webcam'. I only want to return the word if it is fully matched.

Using item.find works but only if the case matches (i.e. upper and lower case must be correct). But I want to return the item regardless of the case, However, I do not wish to match all instances of the string like 'Webcamnew' so using the any() method won't work I think. Does anyone know how to do this..?

```
my_list = ['webcam', 'home', 'Space', 'Maybe later', 'Webcamnew']

for item in my_list:
    if item.find("Webcam") != -1:
        print item
```

Comment: Convert every string you are comparing to lowercase with `string.lower()`

Comment: if there is a way to do it without converting to lower/uppercase that would be useful.

Answer (score 8):

```
my_list = ['webcam', 'home', 'Space', 'Maybe later', 'Webcamnew']

for item in my_list:
    if 'webcam' == item.lower()
        print item.lower()
```

*Note*: Strings are **immutable** in `Python` - it doesn't modify the string in the list.

Comment: if there is a way to do it without converting to lower/uppercase that would be useful as when you convert back you loose the correct case.

Comment: Strings are immutable

Comment: What do you mean "convert back"? The code shown preserves item?

Comment: This is the correct answer. @john `"TESTING".lower()` does not change the case of the original `"TESTING"` string. This is impossible, as strings are immutable in Python (they cannot be changed). It creates a NEW string, with all lowercase letters, and compares that instead.

Comment: Thanks, I see what it does now.

Comment: I see why you asked the question now.

Comment: If this or any of the other answered solved your issue then please accept it so it doesn't remain unanswered.  Happy programming!

Comment: That last statement is hand-wavy, though. List indices are mutable, and the OP was concerned with changing the original list.

Answer (score 5):

If for some reason you REALLY need to compare case insensitive strings (rather than generating a same-case string) you can use regular expressions with the `re.IGNORECASE` flag. This is a terrible idea for what you seem to be trying to do, but the code is:

```
import re

my_list = ['webcam', 'home', 'Space', 'Maybe later', 'Webcamnew']
for item in my_list:
    if re.match("webcam$",item, flags=re.I): # re.I == re.IGNORECASE
        print item
```

The reason this is a Bad Idea is that using regular expressions for simple matching is kind of like using a backhoe to dig post holes. Sure, you can do it, but it's expensive, time-consuming, and has the opportunity to introduce errors you didn't think about until you accidentally swung the boom through your living room window.

Comment: If you want to do this, you will need to use `re.escape()` and append a `$`.

Comment: +1 for alternative route w/ warning

Comment: @GregHewgill why would you need to do `re.escape()`? You're right about `$` though, adding that now.

Comment: @AdamSmith: Well you wouldn't need it for a literal `"webcam"`, but you would need it if you're searching for something taken from user input, for example. A string like `"foo[bar"` is an invalid regex.

Comment: @GregHewgill understood. I don't know if that's part of what the OP needs though, as his example is matching against a literal string. If so it'd be easier to do `re.match("\b"+re.escape(raw_input())+"\b", " ".join(my_list), re.I)`