# Python - Replace string regardless of upper case and lower case with itself plus special characters

Tags: python, string, replace

Given a string:

```
s = "abc, Abc, aBc, abc-def, abca"
```

and a word:

```
w = "abc"
```

I want to modify s in the following way:

`!+abc+!, !+Abc+!, !+aBc+!, abc-def, abca`

In other words, I want to replace any occurrence of `abc` no matter of lowercase or uppercase letters in it, by itself preceded by `!+` and followed by `+!`.

I already know that my question is pretty similar to this question:
[Match string in python regardless of upper and lower case differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313407/match-string-in-python-regardless-of-upper-and-lower-case-differences)

Though, it remains slightly different.

At the moment my solution is pretty dirty and does not work properly:

```
s = "abc, Abc, aBc, abc-def, abca"
w = "abc"
if w in s:
    s = s.replace(w, "!+"+w+"+!")
if w.title() in s:
    s = s.replace(w.title(), "!+"+w.title()+"+!")
```

Comment: You don't need a string as pattern, you need a [case-insensitive regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.I).

Comment: case-insensitive regex is the way to go here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward even without a regex.

```
>>> ', '.join('!+{}+!'.format(x) if x.lower()==w else x for x in s.split(', '))
'!+abc+!, !+Abc+!, !+aBc+!, abc-def, abca'
```

edit: using a list comprehension instead of a generator comprehension is faster, so

```
', '.join(['!+{}+!'.format(x) if x.lower()==w else x for x in s.split(', ')])
```

should be preferred. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python) question and the answer by Raymond Hettinger in particular for the reason.

Comment: What if s is a long sentence, where words are not simply recognizable by splitting the sentence by `s.split(", ")`?

Comment: @Ale then we have a different question.Depending on the complexity of the task, either a regex, multiple regex or a full parser can be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
In [16]: re.sub(r'(?: |^)(abc),',r'!+\1+!,', s, flags=re.I)
Out[16]: '!+abc+!,!+Abc+!,!+aBc+!, abc-def, abca'
```

The patter `(?: |^)(abc),` will match every `abc` that proceeds by a space or the start of the string (`^`) and followed by a comma and replaces it with the first captured group surrounded with your expected characters. Note that `:?` in the first group makes it a non-captured group so the `\1` will refer to `abc`. Also we are using `re.I` flag which is the ignore case flag.

If you also want to keep the spaces just use a captured-group for the first group:

```
In [19]: re.sub(r'( |^)(abc),',r'\1!+\2+!,', s, flags=re.I)
Out[19]: '!+abc+!, !+Abc+!, !+aBc+!, abc-def, abca'
```

Also note that if you want to pass multiple regex as the replacing pattern you can compile the first regex using `re.compile()` and pass the other patterns within a loop:

```
my_regex = re.compile(r'( |^)(abc),')
my_new_result = [my_regex.sub(pattern, s, flags=re.I) for pattern in list_of_patterns]
```

As a more flexible way to deal with `re.sub` you can also pass a function as the replacer, and so more operations on your captured strings. For example if you want to lower case the matched strings:

```
s = "abc, Abc, aBc (abc) abc abc <abc> abc-def, abca"

In [31]: re.sub(r'(^|\W)(abc)($|\W)', lambda x: '{}!+{}+!{}'.format(*x.groups()).lower() if x.group(3) != '-' else x.group(0), s, flags=re.I)
Out[31]: '!+abc+!, !+abc+!, !+abc+! (!+abc+!) !+abc+! abc <!+abc+!> abc-def, abca'
```

Comment: Is it possible to put a variable containing the pattern inside the `re.sub` function instead of the pattern itself? I have to call this procedure several times with patterns that I do not know in advance.

Comment: @Ale Of course. You can just pass the variable instead of the patter, but remember that your variable should be a string proceeds by `r`. You may want to do this in a list comprehension or any kind of loop.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, but it seems to me to be too much specific. I mean, what happens if I have `s = "abc, Abc, aBc (abc) abc abc <abc> abc-def, abca"`? I want the output to be: `!+abc+!, !+abc+!, !+abc+! (!+abc+!) !+abc+! !+abc+! <!+abc+!> abc-def, abca`. I tried with `s = re.sub(r"\b"+w+r"\b", "!+"+w+"+!", s, flags=re.I)`, where `w="abc"`. It outputs `!+abc+!, !+abc+!, !+abc+! (!+abc+!) !+abc+! !+abc+! <!+abc+!> !+abc+!-def, abca` which has 2 errors: 1) It outputs any occurrence in lowercase 2) it matches "abc" in "abc-def".

Comment: Where did you define ´re´? I got this error: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 You need to import it. `import re`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use sub as shown below for the replacement.**
use re.escape() : if there is any special character in the string to be escaped. else, it will work with out that also

```
re.sub(re.escape(value_want_to_replace),'value_to_be_replaced_with', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

**Example: Replacing all Null/NULL/nulL with arpan**

```
   expected_result = "We are doing ignore case replacement for Null, NULL, nulL and space, SPACE, sPace"
   __expected_result = re.sub(re.escape("null"), 'arpan', expected_result, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    print(__expected_result)
```

**Result:**

We are doing ignore case replacement for arpan, arpan, arpan and space, SPACE, sPace